# Docker mysql Outfile permission

Tags: mysql, docker, select-into-outfile

How can I set the permission of outfile when executing via stored procedure
that using a docker mysql, I can manually change the chown -R root:root or chmod -R 777 but whenever the stored procedure of outfile execute it always has a permission or -rw-r---1.

Hope can someone point me to correct way of docker of doing this. I also use to ask chatGPT and follow the procedure but no luck of changing the defined permission set by stored proc outfile.

[image]

-rwxrwxrwx---1 something like that permission or a user of all